# ASP.NET - Changing keyboard input language upon web site starup

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm developing a website where the language is different from English. Is it possible to change keyboard input language to a certain language when the active window/page is the website?

Comment: would you like your OS settings to be changed when you visit some site? it shall be a security nightmare if web apps can change OS configurations of client.

Comment: I understand it, but I think there should be a way to avoid the need of changing the keyboard language manually. I'm sure I'm not the first one to wonder and that there are smart guys around here.

Comment: instead of changing the keyboard language I would recommend you to use some js virtual keyboard like `http://www.greywyvern.com/code/javascript/keyboard` or `http://freecode.com/projects/jsvk`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It is not possible to change the keyboard input language from a web site.

You can suggest that a user use a particular language, but you can't control what they use.

You could detect the user language by inspecting the Server variables

```
var language = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"];
var charset = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET"];
```